# Every Banach space is quotient of $\ell_1(I)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

I'm looking for a book containing the proof that for every Banach space E there is an index I so that E is a quotient space of $\ell_1(I)$. If I can't find the book on google books, it would be great if you could give me the page number, because my paper is due tomorrow and I just need it for a reference. Thank you!

Comment: Is this the reference you needed?

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 1.4.a in:

> J. M. F. Castillo and M. Gonzalez, *Three-space problems in Banach space theory*, Springer Lecture Notes in Math. 1667, 1997.

*Proof*. Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $\{x_i\colon i\in I\}$ be a dense subset of the unit ball of $E$. Define a map $Q\colon \ell_1(I)\to E$ by

$$Q ( (a_i)_{i\in I} ) = \sum_{i\in I} a_i x_i\quad (a_i)_{i\in I} \in \ell_1(I).$$

Then $Q$ is the desired surjection. $\square$

Comment: Just one comment: in their book, they pick a dense subset of the unit _ball_ but they need a dense subset of the unit _sphere_ for the map to be an isometry.

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo, this map is almost never an isometry.

Comment: Which map are you speaking about, precisely? What I meant is simply that in Lemma 1.4.a _op. cit_ they claim that $X$ is linearly isometric to some quotient of $\ell^1(I)$ for some set $I$. The map $Q$ they construct sends $e_\alpha\in\ell^1(I)$ to $x_\alpha$ and this will not be an isometry unless $\Vert x_\alpha\Vert =1$.

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo, this map $Q$ has a kernel so can't be isometric.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Banach space to be separable, I think.

You can find it as Theorem 4.6 in [these notes](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Functional%20Analysis2.pdf) by Piotr Hajlasz.

Comment: Of course, $E$ need not be separable in this case $I$ is just uncountable.