# Every separable Banach space is isomorphic to $\ell_1/A$ for some closed $A\subset \ell_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

How to prove the following mind-blowing fact?

> Let $X$ be a separable Banach space and let $\ell_1$ be the space of all absolutely summable scalar sequences. Then there exists such closed subspace $A\subset \ell_1$ that factor space $\ell_1/A$ and $X$ are isomorphic as normed spaces.

**Edit:**
So what, this is like a classification up to isomorphism of all separable Banach spaces? Each separable Banach space corresponds to some closed subspace of $\ell_1$?

Comment: Please look here (Theorem 2.3.1) http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387281414-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-169533-p61703757

Comment: Your question is a bit garbled.  First of all, $\ell_1$ is the space of absolutely summable scalar sequences, not the space of converging sequences.  Second, $X$ has to be separable in order for $\ell_1/A\cong X$.  (Obviously, nonseparable spaces won't be a quotient of $\ell_1$!)  The proof is in the above link.  Third, quotients are not subspaces.  You have to transfer to the dual $\ell_\infty$, and then every separable space is a closed subspace.

Comment: You might find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089176/tf-sum-1-infty-fnx-n-is-surjective-from-l1-to-a-separable-banach-spa) useful.

Comment: Not every Banach space is separable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes, thanks, it was lost in editing

Comment: @anonymous, thanks a lot for your remarks! I was thinking about convergence of partial sums and wrote the wrong definition of $\ell_1$. Do I understand correctly that your second remark follows from $\ell_1$ being separable and hence all its quotients being separable? About the third, I didn't mean that quotients are subspaces. When I write that each separable Banach space corresponds to some closed subspace of $\ell_1$, I mean this correspondence: $X \to \ell_1/A$

Comment: @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura, thanks a lot! That's very useful article, I'll dig into it. One question though: does the fact that two normed spaces are isometrically isomorphic implies that they are isomorphic as normed spaces? I think the answer is yes, because $\|x\| = \rho(x, 0)$, right?

Comment: Yes you,re right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $\{x_d\colon d\in D\}$ be a dense subset of the unit ball of $X$. Consider the space $\ell_1(D)$ of all absolutely summable sequences on $D$. We define a linear map $T\colon \ell_1(D) \to X$ by

$$T\Big((\lambda_d)_{d\in D}\Big) = \sum_{d\in D}\lambda_d x_d\qquad ((\lambda_d)_{d\in D} \in \ell_1(D)).$$
This is a well-defined linear map as the right-hand side converges absolutely for every $(\lambda_d)_{d\in D}\in \ell_1(D)$, hence it defines an element of $X$. For each $(\lambda_d)_{d\in D} \in \ell_1(D)$ we have $$\|T\big((\lambda_d)_{d\in D}\big)\|\leqslant \sum_{d\in D}\|\lambda_d x_d\|\leqslant \sum_{d\in D}|\lambda_d|=\|(\lambda_d)_{d\in D} \|.$$

Consequently, $T$ is a bounded (actually norm-one) linear operator. [Since $\{x_d\colon d\in D\}$ is dense in the unit sphere of $X$, $T$ is surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089176/tf-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fnx-n-is-surjective-from-ell1-to-a-separable). By the first isomorphism theorem,
$$X\cong \ell_1(D) / \ker T.$$

Note that separability of $X$ means that we may take $D=\mathbb{N}$.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933658/every-banach-space-is-quotient-of-ell-1i/951008#951008)'s a reference to the literature.

Comment: It is not so obvious that $T$ is surjective. It needs more explaining!

Comment: Surjectivity of $T$ (and the fact that $T$ can be chosen so that the quotient map is isometric) is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3682910/22857).