# If $X/F$ is separable, must $X/F$ isomorphic to $F$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space and $F$ is a closed subspace of $X$. Clearly $X/F$ is a Banach space, equipped with quotient norm.

Question: If $X/F$ is separable, must $X/F$ isomorphic to $F$?

The motivation of this question comes from [Corollary $3.4$](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf). It seems that I need this fact to conclude that $F$ is linearly complemented in $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Every separable Banach space is isomorphic to a quotient of $\ell_1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538920/every-banach-space-is-isomorphic-to-ell-1-a-for-some-closed-a-subset-ell-1/1540061#1540061) Certainly most of separable Banach spaces are not isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell_1$.

Answer (score 3):

No, in general, this is very false.

A counterexample can already be obtained by taking $X =\Bbb {R}^3$ and $F=\Bbb {R}^2\times \{0\} $.

Then $\dim X/F=1$, but $\dim F=2$, so that they can not be isomorphic.

But since finite dimensional spaces are always separable and complete, your assumptions hold.

Comment: Then may I know how the author obtained conclusion of corollary $3.4$?

Comment: @GEdgar: No, I did not. Every finite dimensional space is complete and hence a Banach space. The question does not say that the spaces under consideration  should be infinite dimensional.

Comment: My error.  For some reason I thought it said $F = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ instead.

Answer (score 3):

In direct sum $X = l^1 \oplus l^2$, take
subspace $F = 0 \oplus l^2$, which is reflexive, to get quotient
$X / F$ isomorphic to $l^1$, which is separable and not reflexive, and therefore not isomorphic to $F$.