# A non-reflexive Banach space with reflexive quotient space.

Tags: functional-analysis, quotient-spaces

I am looking for an example of a Banach space $B$ such that $B$ is not reflexive but the quotient space $B/C$ is reflexive, for $C$ a closed subspace, $C\subsetneq B.$

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933658/every-banach-space-is-quotient-of-ell-1i) (and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538920/every-separable-banach-space-is-isomorphic-to-ell-1-a-for-some-closed-a-subs)).

Comment: You could also take $C$ to have finite co-dimension.

Comment: Or look at $l_1\oplus l_2$.